# How can I delete many Groups without code deployment?

Tags: security

I've got 889 groups in People and Groups that I would like to delete.
The normal way I can delete one group is:

1. Navigate to the People and Groups management page, /_layouts/groups.aspx
2. Click Edit to get to the Group Settings
3. Scroll to the bottom and Click Delete
   I don't want to do that 889 times, but I don't want to deploy code to the server to do it.

What is the best way to accomplish this? A free third party client based tool would be acceptable or a web services api call if no other way exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my j[Query Library for SharePoint Web Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com) to call the Users and Groups Web Service operation RemoveGroup.  It's not clear where you have the list of 899 groups (or if you do), but if it's in a spreadsheet, make it a SharePoint list and then loop through the items with GetListItems.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Could you share an example with more detail? I have jQuery and I think your library can be used without touching the server, but it would take me a while to work the jQuery syntax unless you help.

Comment: Can you get the 899 groups into a list somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this via PowerShell if that is deployed.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'm trying to avoid server access by RDP or stsadm commands, but this would be a light server approach if others don't work.

Comment: Got it!  That is the big reason I didn't fully elaborate and provide code.  For me, I used to write console apps to do this sort of thing which seems like overkill.  I think PowerShell does a good job of filling the gap if you have access to the server.  In many environments that isn't possible though.